# Best way to move between panes?

Tags: terminal

Switching between panes is a pain on my Mac keyboard. There is only one CTRL key and it's on the same side as the W key. I want to map a new keystroke to make this super efficient, preferably without using the CTRL key at all.

I'm wondering what other folks out there doing to switch between panes to make it as painless as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I really like this for cycling through panes: `map <Tab><Tab> <C-W>w`

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, on linux I'm using `xmodmap` and [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) to use the `Enter` key as the control modifier key when it's hold, and `Enter` when it's pressed.

I do something similar with the capslock key: control when it's hold, and escape when it's pressed.

I don't know Mac well enough to tell you if you could do something similar, but if you did, you would have 2 symmetric control keys, one on the left, the other on the right of the keyboard.

When you have 2 control keys easily accessible for your left and right little fingers, many key sequences involving the control modifier key become easier to type, imho.

In a file sourced by `xmodmap` (I think it could be `~/.Xmodmap`), I have this code:

```
keycode 36 = Hyper_L
remove mod4 = Hyper_L
add control = Hyper_L
keycode 255 = Return
keycode 66 = Control_L
clear lock
add control = Control_L
```

These commands make the `Enter` and capslock key produce the `Control_L` keysym, when the keys are hold.

In a script executed after the machine has started, I have these commands:

```
xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
xcape -e 'Hyper_L=Return'
```

It restores the keysym `Return` on the `Enter` key, and the keysym `Escape` on the capslock key, when the keys are pressed briefly (< 500ms).

---

If you don't want to use external tools, you could remap the prefix `C-w`, which is used to perform various actions on Vim windows, to `gw`.

This idea is from [justinmk](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1x31ng/follow_my_leader/cf7obe5/).
By default, `gw` is a normal operator to format a text-object, or a region of text covered by a motion. For example, you can format the current paragraph hitting `gwip`.
Even though you would lose this operator, you could still use `gq` instead, which seems a more powerful alternative.

`gq` also allows to format text, but, contrary to `gw`, you can control its behavior with the options `'formatexpr'` and `'formatprg'`.

The idea behind using `gw` as a prefix for managing your windows, is to take `g`, which Vim uses by default as a common prefix to build various commands / operators / motions (you can see most of them with `:echo map(taglist('^g.$'), 'v:val.name')`), and add `w` with the mnemonics `window`.

If you wanted to test this solution for a while, you could try this mapping:

```
nnoremap gw <C-w>
```

From then, to switch from a window to another, instead of hitting `C-w w`, you would hit `gww`.
To open the file under the cursor inside a horizontal split window, instead of hitting `C-w f`, you would hit `gwf`. And so on...

Comment: Very interesting. I will definitely come back to this and try these tips out.